# Help with Error 1061 - Call to a possibly undefined method

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, remoting

First off, here's the exact error I'm getting:

`Error 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method _initRemoteClassAlias through a reference with a static type Class`

So, that being said, here's what I think I know about that. It is tying to call a method named `_initRemoteClassAlias` but cannot find it. So here's my guess where my confusion/problem comes in. The method it is trying to call was created automatically by FlashBuilder in the _Super Class of a PHP script I have written. (in this case the error is stemming from : services.cascobackend._Super_CASCOBackend.as) - Here's the first little bit of code from the _Super Class in question:

```
package services.cascobackend
{
import com.adobe.fiber.core.model_internal;
import com.adobe.fiber.services.wrapper.RemoteObjectServiceWrapper;
import com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility;
import mx.rpc.AbstractOperation;
import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
import mx.rpc.remoting.Operation;
import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;
import valueObjects.Ticket;

import mx.collections.ItemResponder;
import com.adobe.fiber.valueobjects.AvailablePropertyIterator;

[ExcludeClass]
internal class _Super_CASCOBackend extends com.adobe.fiber.services.wrapper.RemoteObjectServiceWrapper
{

// Constructor
public function _Super_CASCOBackend()
{
    // initialize service control
    _serviceControl = new mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject();

    // initialize RemoteClass alias for all entities returned by functions of this service
    valueObjects.Ticket._initRemoteClassAlias();

    var operations:Object = new Object();
    var operation:mx.rpc.remoting.Operation;

    operation = new mx.rpc.remoting.Operation(null, "throwExceptionOnError");
     operation.resultType = Object;
    operations["throwExceptionOnError"] = operation;
    operation = new mx.rpc.remoting.Operation(null, "getTicketsByUser");
     operation.resultElementType = valueObjects.Ticket;
    operations["getTicketsByUser"] = operation;

    _serviceControl.operations = operations;
    _serviceControl.convertResultHandler = com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility.convertResultHandler;
    _serviceControl.source = "CASCOBackend";
    _serviceControl.endpoint = "http://localhost/CMphp/public/gateway.php";


     preInitializeService();
     model_internal::initialize();
}
```

And the specific line the error is happening at is:

```
valueObjects.Ticket._initRemoteClassAlias();
```

In the application I have made (obviously) a value object named Ticket that beings like this:

```
package valueObjects
{
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass(alias="Ticket")]

public class Ticket
{
        public var ticketid:int;
        public var ticketNumber:String;
etc...
etc...
```

The PHP function that it is referencing simply grabs all items with certain parameters and returns a Ticket[] array with the results as individual Ticket items like this:

```
...
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $rows = array();
    $row = new Ticket();

    mysqli_bind_result($stmt, $row->ticketid, etc...
```

Also - when I run the test of this function in FlashBuilder it returns the items just as I expect, even WITH the error about the _initRemoteClassAlias showing. And if I simply comment out that line in question the code just doesn't return anything when ran (it still returns values when tested in FB though)

So - I've messed with this for HOURS and looked around for answers, but I am out of ideas. Hopefully you have some!

Thanks in advance for your help!
-CS

EDIT:::EDIT:::

Okay - here's the ENTIRE _Super code that Flex created:

```
    /**
 * This is a generated class and is not intended for modification.  To customize  behavior
 * of this service wrapper you may modify the generated sub-class of this class - CASCOBackend.as.
 */
 package services.cascobackend
 {
 import com.adobe.fiber.core.model_internal;
 import com.adobe.fiber.services.wrapper.RemoteObjectServiceWrapper;
 import com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility;
 import mx.rpc.AbstractOperation;
 import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
 import mx.rpc.remoting.Operation;
 import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;
 import valueObjects.Ticket;

 import mx.collections.ItemResponder;
 import com.adobe.fiber.valueobjects.AvailablePropertyIterator;

 [ExcludeClass]
 internal class _Super_CASCOBackend extends                com.adobe.fiber.services.wrapper.RemoteObjectServiceWrapper
 {

     // Constructor
     public function _Super_CASCOBackend()
     {
    // initialize service control
    _serviceControl = new mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject();

    // initialize RemoteClass alias for all entities returned by functions of this service
    valueObjects.Ticket._initRemoteClassAlias();

    var operations:Object = new Object();
    var operation:mx.rpc.remoting.Operation;

    operation = new mx.rpc.remoting.Operation(null, "throwExceptionOnError");
     operation.resultType = Object;
    operations["throwExceptionOnError"] = operation;
    operation = new mx.rpc.remoting.Operation(null, "getTicketsByUser");
     operation.resultElementType = valueObjects.Ticket;
    operations["getTicketsByUser"] = operation;

    _serviceControl.operations = operations;
    _serviceControl.convertResultHandler = com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility.convertResultHandler;
    _serviceControl.source = "CASCOBackend";
    _serviceControl.endpoint = "http://localhost/CMphp/public/gateway.php";


     preInitializeService();
     model_internal::initialize();
}

//init initialization routine here, child class to override
protected function preInitializeService():void
{
    destination = "CASCOBackend";

}


/**
  * This method is a generated wrapper used to call the 'throwExceptionOnError' operation. It returns an mx.rpc.AsyncToken whose 
  * result property will be populated with the result of the operation when the server response is received. 
  * To use this result from MXML code, define a CallResponder component and assign its token property to this method's return value. 
  * You can then bind to CallResponder.lastResult or listen for the CallResponder.result or fault events.
  *
  * @see mx.rpc.AsyncToken
  * @see mx.rpc.CallResponder 
  *
  * @return an mx.rpc.AsyncToken whose result property will be populated with the result of the operation when the server response is received.
  */
public function throwExceptionOnError(link:Object) : mx.rpc.AsyncToken
{
    var _internal_operation:mx.rpc.AbstractOperation = _serviceControl.getOperation("throwExceptionOnError");
    var _internal_token:mx.rpc.AsyncToken = _internal_operation.send(link) ;
    return _internal_token;
}

/**
  * This method is a generated wrapper used to call the 'getTicketsByUser' operation. It returns an mx.rpc.AsyncToken whose 
  * result property will be populated with the result of the operation when the server response is received. 
  * To use this result from MXML code, define a CallResponder component and assign its token property to this method's return value. 
  * You can then bind to CallResponder.lastResult or listen for the CallResponder.result or fault events.
  *
  * @see mx.rpc.AsyncToken
  * @see mx.rpc.CallResponder 
  *
  * @return an mx.rpc.AsyncToken whose result property will be populated with the result of the operation when the server response is received.
  */
public function getTicketsByUser(userid:Object) : mx.rpc.AsyncToken
{
    var _internal_operation:mx.rpc.AbstractOperation = _serviceControl.getOperation("getTicketsByUser");
    var _internal_token:mx.rpc.AsyncToken = _internal_operation.send(userid) ;
    return _internal_token;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Who made this code?  It's *very* messy....

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough, `_initRemoteClassAlias()` is not part of Ticket, or that it's not `static public`.

I don't know who made the code, but it's not following any standards that I can see.

Comment: FlashBuilder created the _Super class code - The rest of the examples are just there to show how the Ticket object begins, the PHP section is to show how the array was being built, etc.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I've never seen this kind of generated code from Flash Builder.  Anywho, the function you're referring to is useless so you can just comment it out.

Comment: Also, what isn't static public? The _Super file, the Ticket.as ??? sorry if it's a dumb question...

Comment: Yeah - but when I commented it out - it won't return anything...?

Comment: static public would relate to Ticket because you're trying to reference a class, not an instance.  Comment out that line and instead add a `private var _ticket:Ticket;` right above the constructor and see if that works.

Comment: Okay - when I did that it did (2) things during runtime:

Comment: 1) TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. - also did not return the data.....There are NO null values in any field in the SQL DB

Comment: stop spamming the comments... Also, try debugging the application.